# discard last or first group after group_by by referencing group directly

Tags: r, group-by

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(rep(letters[1],3),rep(letters[2],3),rep(letters[3],3)),
                 B=rnorm(9),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
```

**I don't know if there's a way to do this**, but what I'd like to know is if there's way to discard the last group **by directly referencing the groups** after `group_by(A)` to get the desired output:

```
  A          B
1 a -0.4900863
2 a  1.4106594
3 a -0.2245738
4 b -0.2124955
5 b  0.6963785
6 b  0.9151825
```

**I AM INTERESTED IN SOLUTIONS THAT DIRECTLY WORK AT THE GROUPS LEVEL**

For instance, something like:

```
df %>% group_by(A) %>% head(.Groups,-1)
or
df %>% group_by(A) %>% Groups[1:2]
```

**I AM NOT INTERESTED IN THE FOLLOWING KINDS OF SOLUTIONS**

```
df %>% filter(!(A == max(A)))
df %>% filter(!(A %in% max(A)))
```

**OR OTHER SOLUTIONS THAT DO NOT REQUIRE `group_by` TO WORK**

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(A) %>% group_indices(.) %in% 1:2 %>% df[.,]`

Comment: It's a bit like `df %>% filter(!(A == max(A)))`, but I'll ask you to post as an answer if I don't receive a better one in the next 24 hours or so...Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was assuming you were not supposed to be assuming that we knew in advance what the number of groups might be. Try using the `labels` attribute:

```
 all_but_last <- df %>% group_by(A) %>% attr("labels") %>% head(-1)
  A
1 a
2 b
```

... to extract desired rows

```
 > df %>% filter(A %in% all_but_last[[1]])
  A            B
1 a -0.799026840
2 a -0.712402478
3 a  0.685320094
4 b  0.971492883
5 b -0.001479117
6 b -0.817766296
```

Helps to use `dput` to look at the actual contents of a "grouped_df":

```
dput( df %>% group_by(A) )
structure(list(A = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
"c"), B = c(-0.799026840397576, -0.712402478350695, 0.685320094252465, 
0.971492883452258, -0.00147911717469651, -0.817766295631676, 
-1.00112471676908, 1.88145909873596, -0.305560178617216)), .Names = c("A", 
"B"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "A", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:2, 3:5, 6:8), group_sizes = c(3L, 3L, 3L), biggest_group_size = 3L, 
 labels = structure(list(
                       A = c("a", "b", "c")), 
                       row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                       class = "data.frame", 
                       vars = "A", drop = TRUE, .Names = "A"))
```

Note that the labels are a data.frame so you could have further applied `unlist` to the result that became `all_but_last` and you then would not have needed to extract its value with `"[["`.

Comment: Looking at `dput` does help. Thanks. I'll wait a bit before accepting an answer still. Appreciate it.

Comment: No need to wait. You can always change later.

Comment: That's a bit like handing out presents and taking them away immediately. ;-)

Comment: Not really. Most people who have been answering questions for a while have a fairly detached attitude. We don't take it as an insult to see that another answer provided more useful information, or was faster, or more in keeping with your individual learning style. You are the best judge of an answers value ... to you.

Comment: Fair enough. With 180K points, what's a few more...a few less.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(A) %>% 
  group_indices(.) %in% 1:2 %>%
  df[.,]
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  grp := .GRP, A][grp %in% unique(grp)[1:2]][, grp := NULL][]
```